# Ubuntu Software Center Downloads not showing up on software launcher

Tags: software-center

I've tried installing several apps on the software center and I cannot find the apps when I use the software launcher. The only way to open the app is by looking for it in the software center and opening it through there. Is this normal?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the software launcher with the desktop search. I can't find the app with desktop search.

Comment: The thing that I cannot find is the app I downloaded, not the desktop search. Sorry for the confusion. when searching, I can't find apps downloaded via the software center

Comment: Can you provide an example? When I install from Software Center, I can see my applications in Desktop Search.

Comment: For example, I installed an app called postman and I can't find it anywhere. When I use Desktop search, the app doesn't show up. This has happened downloading slack, vs code, and others. I usually have to go to the app's website to actually install it through their download. The problem right now is that I can't seem to install the application with the download and I also can't install it with the software center.

Comment: Postman is a snap. If so, seems a lot like https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/ubuntu-18-04-cannot-find-snap-applications/11542/ . Does a logout/login cure the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a *launcher* that holds all your applications automatically.
It's a *shortcut bar* where YOU place the most frequently used.

For infrequently-used (or new) applications, you can use Software Center or the Desktop Search. Personally, I find Desktop Search easier to use.

There are many ways to reach Desktop Search in Gnome:

- On the Shortcut Bar, look for the nine-little-boxes-grid icon, usually near the bottom.
- On the Keyboard, simply press the Windows (super) key.
- At the top-of-screen menus, look on the top-left and click on "Activities"